# Probability parameters in Tensorflow Object Detection API image preprocessesing

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am training a ssd_inception neural network using the Tensorflow Object Detection API. In the pipeline config file, there are [preprocessor options](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) to augment images during training. Is there any way to introduce probability of applying a given preprocessing? E.g 20% that the image will change contrast etc. If not, are there any plans to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have any current plan to do that. But feel free to send in a pull request. We are happy to review.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py and https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py to get started.